# Access RaspberryPi with hostname through VPN server

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm trying to use a VPN to remotely connect to a raspberryPi using its hostname but I can't make it work.

I have the following setup :

- **VPN server** on a Synology device
- **RaspberryPi 3** on network A with openvpn client installed, running and successfully connected to the VPN server
- **Windows 10 PC** on network B with openvpn client installed, running and successfully connected to the VPN server

I also want to add the fact that the 2 networks (A & B) are 2 WiFi hotspots created by 2 different smartphones.

Here is a [representation of the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSeP4.png) to give you a better understanding (I hope).

From the PC, I can ping and ssh to the RaspberryPi using its ip address (the one given by the VPN) without problems.
However I can't do the same using its hostname (I get the "unreachable host" message when trying to ping).

I tried manually setting up the DNS to use the synology DDNS on both the raspberryPi and the PC with the following methods :

- **PC** : I followed [this tutorial](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-change-dns-server-windows-mac) to change the DNS of the VPN interface
- **RaspberryPi** : I edited the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file to add `static domain_name_servers=<SYNOLOGY DDNS IP>` at the end of the file

But my PC still can't ping the raspberryPi's hostname...

I'm quite a beginner with networking and it's very likely that I'm missing something, I hope someone can help me with this.

Have a good day :)

Comment: You want to reach the RPi with its local hostname, right? If the Synology provides a local DNS, the question is whether it is aware of the local hostnames of other network members. Especially when the RPi does not use DHCP but a static IP, this is not guaranteed. A solution could be mDNS via e.g. Avahi-Daemon so that the RPi broadcasts its local hostname to network members. Not sure whether this works thorough the VPN OOTB, though, but a local DNS server may pick it up then as well.

Comment: Yes I want to reach the RPi with its local hostname. That make sense, I'll try it !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the DDNS of the synology is a service to connect your dynamically assigned IP (by your ISP) to a public DNS.

It's at least how I connected my "internet box" to no-ip.com...
That way when the box reboots and gets a new IP ( ISP using dhcp ), it notifies the no-ip servers so they can update the IP on my public DNS record. The URL will point to the new IP of my server.

What you need is a **local DNS** server.

On my local network, I did it by using the ( not very good ) interface provided on my internet box ( there is a tab to assign a hostname to a fixed IP ).
But in your case if you are using a smartphone as a gateways I don't think there would be such a feature available.

Maybe you can host ( or enable ? ) the local DNS feature on your synology. Otherwise you can deploy a DNS on your local network ( [Pi-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-hole) on your Pi for example ).
Then add the DNS in the list of DNS server to query for resolution.

( As for the tutorial, but most likely can be done as on option of the VPN tunnel on the synology )

Note : On my private network the name resolution is still random with my box, but it work better if I add a `.home`  after the name.

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! Globally I understand what needs to be done, but in practice I'm not sure about a few details.

Comment: For example what do you mean when you say "add the DNS in the list of DNS server to query for resolution" ? Do you mean if I install a DNS locally on the RPi I also have to add its address in `etc/dhcpcd.conf` ? Wouldn't it be the same as the RPi IP ?

Also with the ".home" extension, similarly I used to add ".local" extension to RPi hostnames to access them, but I'm not sure why it's needed and how can I know if it's ".home" or ".local" ?